# $K \leq H_1 \leq H_2 \leq G$, and that $K \trianglelefteq G$ and $H_1 \trianglelefteq H_2$. show that $[H_2 : H_1] = [H_2/K : H_1/K]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Suppose that $K \leq H_1 \leq H_2 \leq G$, and that $K \trianglelefteq G$ and $H_1 \trianglelefteq H_2$. Using only Lagrange, show that $[H_2 : H_1] = [H_2/K : H_1/K]$.
(It's not enough to just write down some big fractions and cancel the $K$'s.)

---

**Theorem 6.10 Lagrange**. Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then
$|G|/|H| = [G : H]$ is the number of distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$. In particular, the number
of elements in $H$ must divide the number of elements in $G$

---

$$
\begin{aligned}
.[H_2 : H_1]  &= \frac{|H_2|}{|H_1|} \\
&= \frac{|H_2|}{|K|} \cdot \frac{|K|}{|H_1|} \\
&= \frac{|H_2|}{|K|} \div \frac{|H_1|}{|K|} \\
&= \frac{|H_2/K|}{|H_1/K|} \\
&= \left|\frac{H_2/K}{H_1/K}\right| \\
&= [H_2/K : H_1/K].
\end{aligned}
$$

Im not sure if what i did was correct and I also didnt use only Lagranges theorem. is this a good proof ?

Comment: Why do you have "and $K\subseteq G$ and $H_1\subseteq H_2$"? You have $H_1\leq H_2$, i.e., $H_1$ is a subgroup of $H_2$. That **implies** that $H_1$  must be a subset of $H_2$; it's a prerequisite to being a subgroup. Likewise, $K$ is a subgroup of $H_1$, which is a subgroup of $H_2$, which is a subgroup of $G$, so $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and hence in particular a subset. Why do you need to specify that they are subsets?

Comment: You cannot write $\frac{|H_2|}{|H_1|}$ unless you have that both quantifies are finite. You do not have any assumption on finiteness here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have no idea, this is what my teacher wrote. i too thought the same thing

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I assume its finite because throughout the whole semester, we never really talked about infinite groups except the integers and complex numbers. so i assume were talking about finite groups since im taking an introductory group theory class

Comment: It does not follow that all groups are finite. Any introductory group theory class will certainly consider the group of integers under addition, which is infinite. The result holds for infinite groups, so there is no reason to restrict to finite groups. My point is that your entire argument is *already* nonsense if you do not explicitly exclude infinite groups. Moreover, what you are doing is *precisely* "writ[ing] down some big fractions and cancelling out the $K$s", so this is clearly not the answer expected.

Comment: I suspect that you don't actually have $K\subseteq G$, but rather $K\triangleleft G$ (so that you can compute the quotient), and not $H_1\subseteq H_2$, but rather $H_1\triangleleft H_2$. I mean, really. If the problem doesn't make sense, why are you not asking your teacher to clarify it, instead of strangers who are not taking the class with you?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh wow i saw the mistake that i  just did .you were right , it should be normal and not subset. I got it confused with another problem i was doing. sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But im didnt cancel any K, i introduced K's . I cant find any other way of doing it otherwise .

Comment: Introducing $K$ is the same as cancelling them. Read your equations bottom to top, and you are cancelling them. Saying that $a=c$ is equivalent to $ab=cb$ when $b\neq 0$ is fine, but claiming that this does not require cancellation is false.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can i have a hint please . I have no idea how to show this is true. the only way i can think of would be to show a bijection from $[H_2 : H_1]$ to $[H_2/K : H_1/K]$. but even from there i cant find anything

Comment: The first thing you need to to is to present **exactly** what version of Lagrange's Theorem you have; the problem asks you to "us[e] only Lagrange", but there are multiple ways to state Lagrange, some weaker than others. Some state it only for finite groups, some state it in generality as a bijection between cosets in the case of subgroups $M_1\leq M_2\leq G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as $H_2$ is finite, your use of Lagrange's theorem is correct.
When in doubt, say explicitly the reason behind each deduction you made:
$$
\begin{align*}
[H_2:H_1] &= \frac{|H_2|}{|H_1|} \tag{Lagrange} \\
&= \frac{|H_2|/|K|}{|H_1|/|K|} \tag{$|K|\ne 0$} \\
&= \frac{[H_2:K]}{[H_1:K]} \tag{Lagrange} \\
&= \frac{|H_2/K|}{|H_1/K|} \tag{$K\unlhd H_1$ and $K\unlhd H_2$} \\
&= [H_2/K:H_1/K] \tag{Lagrange}
\end{align*}
$$

Now, if $H_2$ is infinite, then the finite version of Lagrange theorem cannot be applied.
In this case, it is also hard to apply the infinite version, at least to me.
One way is to simply construct an explicit bijection between the two quotient groups.
Define $\phi:H_2/H_1\to (H_2/K)/(H_1/K)$ by
$$
\phi(aH_1)=(aK)(H_1/K)
$$
for all $a\in H_2$.
The map is well-defined and injective
because for all $a,b\in H_2$,
we have $a^{-1}b\in H_1$ if and only if $a^{-1}bK\in H_1/K$.
It is also clearly surjective.
The required formula is thus proved.

By the way, $\phi$ is actually a homomorphism, so it shows that $H_2/H_1\cong (H_2/K)/(H_1/K)$.
This is known as the third isomorphism theorem.

---

Instead of doing it all at once,
the map $\phi$ above can be constructed fairly naturally:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_2 @>{\pi_2}>> H_2/K\\
@V\pi_{1} VV @VV\pi_3 V \\
H_2/H_1 @>{\phi}>> \frac{H_2/K}{H_1/K}
\end{CD} \tag{1}
$$
Well, this might be a bit stretching for a beginner,
but let me explain.

First, there is actually a defining property of "taking a quotient",
called the universal property of quotient groups:

> Let $G,H$ be groups and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$.
> Let $f:G\to H$ be any homomorphism.
> Let $\pi:G\to G/N$ be the canonical projection,
> i.e. $\pi(g)=gN$ for all $g\in G$.
> Suppose $N\le \text{ker} f$.
> Then there is a unique homomorphism $\phi:G/N\to H$ such that
> $f=\phi \circ \pi$.
> Diagrammatically,
> $$
> \require{AMScd} \begin{CD} G @>\forall f>> H\\ 
> @V\pi VV     
> {_{\rlap{\quad\ \ \ \ \exists ! \phi}}
> \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(330deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{2em}{0em}]{}}}}\\
> G/N \end{CD}
> $$
> the above diagram commutes, i.e. $f=\phi\circ \pi$.

Despite being a big chunk of statements,
it's not that hard to understand and prove.
The main takeaway is that,
given a homomorphism $f$, under certain condition,
we can decompose it as $f=\phi \circ \pi$ for some homomorphism $\phi$.
It is as if we are doing factorization of homomorphisms.

Back to the $(1)$ above.
The $\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3$ are canonical projections (the maps that send a group to its quotient group).
These projections are always surjective (not hard to show),
and the kernels of these are always the normal subgroups that are being modded.

We can now apply the universal property,
choosing
$G=H_2$, $H=(H_2/K)/(H_1/K)$,
$N=H_1$,
$f=\pi_3\circ \pi_2$
and $\pi=\pi_1$.
It is not hard to verify that $\text{ker} f=H_1$.
Now, we can then decompose $f$ as $f=\phi\circ \pi_1$.
From the fact that $\text{ker}(f)=H_1$,
$\pi_1$ is surjective,
and $\text{ker}(\phi\circ \pi_1)=\pi_1^{-1}(\phi^{-1}(\{H_1/K\}))$,
we can deduce that $\text{ker}(\phi)=\{H_1\}$,
which is the trivial group in $H_2/H_1$.
This shows that $\phi$ is injective.
Also, $\phi$ is surjective because $\pi_3\circ \pi_2$ is surjective
($h\circ g$ surjective implies $h$ surjective).
This shows that $\phi$ is a bijection, as desired.

Comment: im not too sure about this notation: $(aK)(H_1/K)$ Why would an element of this coset be of that form?  i can't really visualize a quotient group modded another quotient group

Comment: @user20194358 You don't have to visualize it. A coset of $H$ in $G$ is of the form $gH$, where $g\in G$. Now, let $H=H_1/K$ and $G=H_2/K$. Then $g$ is an element of $H_2/K$, so $g$ takes the form $aK$, where $a\in H_2$. Then $gH=(aK)(H_1/K)$, which is the desired form.

Comment: That said, instead of constructing the map at once, it's clearer and perhaps more insightful to construct it step-by-step. Let me update my answer to explain.

Comment: thanks this makes sense but wouldn't you argue that it would be important to be able to visualize a group modded by another group in the same way i can visualize quotient groups

Comment: @user20194358 I guess you can visualize a quotient group with rectangles and sub-rectangles, but at some point you will have to develop the ability to think of them _abstractly_, though if you study topology or geometry, there do exist a lot of "visualizable" quotient groups, such as $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, which is a torus.

Comment: Also, quotient groups are more commonly thought of as a group with extra relations. Consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for example. You can think of this quotient group as the normal $\mathbb{Z}$, but with the extra relations that all elements in $2\mathbb{Z}$ are considered as $0$ (and from this all other elements have to be $1$). This concept is quite important when you study other things like group presentation or field extensions.

Comment: @user20194358 Updated answer to include a more natural way to construct $\phi$. Ignore it if it's too confusing though :)

Comment: thxs, your explanation made a lot of sense